# Check page and get form names and match them up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery/JavaScript and I am wondering if it's possible to get form names on a page and match them up and execute code depending if they're found.

Now thinking about it, what I am doing might not work and might explain why it's not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var formName = $('form').attr('name');
    if(formName == "carts_list_form"){
        console.log("form loaded");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<form action="/admin.php" method="post" target="" name="carts_list_form" class="cm-processed-form cm-check-changes">
```

Comment: We'd need to your the HTML to help with this.

Comment: Ill provide the form part sure, updating now.

Comment: What you have above should work fine (see https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/g7p737jw/). If you're not seeing the console log then the issue must lie elsewhere. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yea i see that, might it be if other forms are on the page? its an admin area and has some search forms as well..

Comment: If the class is unique you can target that rather than the element - var formName = $('.cm-processed-form').attr('name'); If not, you'll need to give it a unique id and target that instead.

Comment: I cant add IDs as it some software and no hooks tpl / php to apply and ID so cant touch the main files otherwise changes will be lost if software is upgraded so just to do a work around... if makes sense.

Comment: Try $('form[name="carts_list_form"]'), that selector should actually give you the object of the exact form you are looking for. You can then check the .length and see if it is greater than zero. A different approach which may be slightly off base of your end goal but it will return whether or not the form is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple forms in your page `$('form').attr('name')` will only return the name of the first one.

If you want to check for the existence of a form with a specific name use:

```
if ($("form[name='carts_list_form']").length)
{
    console.log("form loaded");
}
```